# How to exclude properties from serialization based on their values?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, properties

To communicate with a web API, I have created a few classes which will be serialized to XML and sent to the API. The API only accepts these XMLs if they only hold properties with non-default values.

How can I leave out properties during serialization?

Suppose I have a class as follows (simplified example):

```
[XmlRoot("SomeData")]
public class SomeData
{
    [XmlElement("rangeX")]
    public int RangeX { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("rangeY")]
    public int RangeY { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("rangeZ")]
    public int RangeZ { get; set; }
}
```

An object which has a non-default value for RangeX and RangeY should thus be serialized to an XML which only holds tags for rangeX and rangeY.

I have found how to leave out null values, but this is not what I want - the default value could very well be different from null.

Thanks!

Comment: Try using LINQ on it.  For example something like  `var newSomeData = existingSomeData.Select( x => x );`  prior to serializing.

Comment: @KraangPrime would you be able to exclude a _property_ that way?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis - yes if you use that same method to 'convert' to a new Class that doesn't have the property.  Your solution is pretty sexy tho

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "secret" *ShouldSerializeXxx()* method:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeRangeX()
{
    return RangeX != someDefaultValue;
}
```

There are a ton of examples when you search for *ShouldSerialize Default Value*, it's just hard to find if you don't know what you're looking for.

Here is a link to help get you started : [Defining Default Values with the ShouldSerialize and Reset Methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Added MSDN link for the requisite aforementioned information  :)

Answer (score 1):

You can gain full control on how the objects of your class are serialized when you implement the [`IXmlSerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) interface (only including the code to write the data, since that is your immediate question):

```
public class SomeData : IXmlSerializable
{
    public int RangeX { get; set; }

    public int RangeY { get; set; }

    public int RangeY { get; set; }

    public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("SomeData");
        if (RangeX != 0)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("rangeX", RangeX.ToTring());
        }
        if (RangeY != 0)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("rangeY", RangeY.ToTring());
        }
        if (RangeZ != 0)
        {
            writer.WriteElementString("rangeZ", RangeZ.ToTring());
        }
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }

    public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        //Implement if needed
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted the solution posted by C.Evenhuis because it means less changes in our existing code base. However, the solution you posted has taught me how to have full control over the resulting XML, so I would like to explicitly thank you for posting!!